# How to update value of a key in a immutable tree map in Scala

Tags: scala, hashmap, treemap

I'm using Scala 2.11 and i'm trying to update the value of a key in the tree map. I tried using updated:

```
private val xyz = List(0, 100000, 500000, 1000000)
private val abc = List (0, 5, 25, 50)
private var a = TreeMap.empty[Int, TreeMap[Int, Int]] ++ xyz.map { 
        aa => aa -> (TreeMap.empty[Int, Int] ++ abc.map(bb => bb -> 0))
    }
a(xyz(0)).foreach { 
        case (key, value) =>
            if (key < 50) {
                a(xyz(0)) = a(xyz(0)).updated(key, 5)
            }
    }
```

And got the error:

```
 value update is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[Int,scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[Int,Int]]
```

Is it possible to update it? Or could someone please help me replicate the logic using a Java Tree Map since that will also allow me to use floorEntry and ceilingEntry functions. I tried converting to java tree map and it generated a regular map, not a tree map:

```
private var a = TreeMap.empty[Int, TreeMap[Int, Int]] ++ xyz.map { 
    aa => aa -> (TreeMap.empty[Int, Int] ++ abc.map(bb => bb -> 0)).asJava
}
private var b = a.asJava
```

Comment: I don't understand. If you _want_ to use `java.util.TreeMap` what's stopping you?

Comment: I'm very new to Scala and the documentation for same is very limited. I'm not really able to replicate the logic of constructing the tree map from 2 lists. I thought immutable scala tree map would be good but facing issues with that as well.

Comment: If you want to change a value in a immutable structure you have to create a new structure with the new value. This is typically achieved with `map` operations. Then it's up to you to know if you want mutable or immutable.

Comment: I want a mutable tree map and that's not possible in Scala 2.11. I tried converting the tree map to java tree map and it generates a regular map and not java tree map. Edited the question to include the java conversion. Could you please help @GaëlJ @jwvh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting confused between `var/val` and `mutable/immutable`.

I think you correctly understood the difference between `val` and `var`, that the former is an immutable variable and later is mutable. ie, if you try to reassign the object assigned as `val` you will get an error.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap

val tm = TreeMap(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)
tm = TreeMap(1->2)
      ^
   error: reassignment to val
```

But a `var` can be mutated:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap

var tm = TreeMap(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)
tm = TreeMap(1->2)
// mutated tm
```

Notice that in the latter case, even though we are mutating the variable, we are not mutating the collection itself, we are assigning a new `TreeMap`. As we were using `scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap` it cant be mutated.

Instead, if we had used `scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap`, it has an `update` function

```
import scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap

val tm = TreeMap(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)
tm.update(1, 5)
tm //TreeMap(1 -> 5, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)
```

Once you change `scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap` to `scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap`, this will work

```
a(xyz(0)).foreach{ case (key, value) =>
  if(key < 50){
    a(xyz(0)) = a(xyz(0)).updated(key, 5) //addOne(key, 5) if 2.13+
  }
}
```

**EDIT** using `java.util.TreeMap`

```
 private val xyz = List(0, 100000, 500000, 1000000)
 private val abc = List(0, 5, 25, 50)

 import java.util.{TreeMap => JTreeMap}

 val jTreeMap = xyz.foldLeft(new JTreeMap[Int, JTreeMap[Int, Int]]()) { (acc, elem) =>
   acc.put(
     elem,
     abc.foldLeft(new JTreeMap[Int, Int]()) { (acc2, elem2) =>
       acc2.put(elem2, 0)
       acc2
     }
   )
   acc
 }
 //Map created

 jTreeMap.get(xyz.head).replaceAll{
   //hack for scala 2.11.x
   new java.util.function.BiFunction[Int, Int, Int]{
     def apply(key: Int, value: Int) = if (value < 5) 5 else value
   }
 }
 //value edited
```

Comment: I’m using Scala 2.11 and hence can’t use mutable tree maps. Can You help me replicate the same logic mentioned above using Java Tree Map?

Comment: Check the update.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to update an immutable object, you can only create a new immutable object from the old one. So the code needs to create a new `TreeMap` from the original one with different values as necessary.

The code looks like this:

```
val newMap = a.map{
  case (k, v) if k == xyz(0) =>
    k -> v.map {
      case (k2, v2) if k2 < 50 =>
        k2 -> 5
      case (k2, v2) =>
        k2 -> v2
    }
  case (k, v) =>
    k -> v
}
```

This breaks down to an outer `map` that looks for matching keys in the outer `TreeMap`, and an inner `map` that looks for matching keys in the inner `TreeMap`. Pattern matching (`case`) is used to implement the match tests, and also to extract the keys and values.

Each `map` has one `case` that selects the values to be modified, and a second case that leaves other values unchanged. The first case returns the original key with a modified value while the second case just returns the original values (`k -> v`).

---

Also note that `var` applies to a variable, not the contents of a variable. It indicates whether the variable can be updated to refer to a different object, but says nothing about whether the object that the variable refers to can be updated. `var` is rarely used in Scala because it goes against a clean functional design.

Comment: Ah got it! Thank you so much for clarifying that. However I will be having a lot of if else conditions on the key and this code would get a bit complicated. Could you tell how I can replicate the logic of constructing the nested tree map from 2 lists by using Java mutable tree map instead?

Comment: Simplify the code by writing a function that calculates the conditions on the key, and give it a meaningful name. `case (k, v) if matchingKey(k) =>`. If you make it a local function it can access values in the outer function to avoid having to pass other values to the matching function.  e.g. `def matchingKey(k: Int) = k == xyz(0)`